# Any better way to determine source of light by analyzing the electromagnectic spectrum of the light

Tags: sensor, light-sensor

## Project overview

I am tasked to develop a microprocessor based device that when shown a light upon, can determine the source of the light (Natural light, Flourescent Bulbs, LED Bulbs, Incandescent Bulbs, Flame - Forest fire). At this stage, only the visible light is considered.

From my research, the only way to differentiate the source of light is by analyzing the emission spectrum and matching it closely to [known values](https://www.comsol.com/blogs/calculating-the-emission-spectra-from-common-light-sources/). Example:

[image]

## Solutions considered

#### Measuring RGB composition ratio of the light

I have considered going this route as it doesn't seem too complicated, smaller device, can be integrated easily into the bigger project as a forest fire detector and even suggested by my supervisor.
But I have doubts that this would be very accurate as some light sources might have close values (the intensity is what is being measured on a ball park wavelength).

The sensor I am looking at currently is the [Hamamatsu’s S10917-35GT RGB color sensor](https://www.hamamatsu.com/jp/en/product/alpha/R/4153/S10917-35GT/index.html), sensitive to only the required wavelengths.

#### Building a high resolution spectrograph with a diffraction grating film

This route is much more complicated and requires external processing of the images to determine the light source. Basically, you build a spectrograph with a diffraction grating film and a high resolution camera. The image is processed with a computer software to plot the emission spectrum graph and you can analyse the graph to determine the light source. [Development guide is here](http://sci-toys.com/scitoys/scitoys/light/spectrograph/spectrograph.html)

Unfortunately, this is not very convenient as we would prefer the device's primary objective to function on it's own without any networking.

## So, the question

- Is there any drawback on my first solution?
- Is there a better solution? Preferably can fit on a standalone device?
- This would probably be far fetched but is there a sensor out there that can analyse a light emission and provide intensity values on a range of chosen wavelengths? Or atleast something that would help me build a device that does such.

Comment: Links to the missing hyperlinks below (needs a higher reputation to post more than 2 links)

[1]: https://www.comsol.com/blogs/calculating-the-emission-spectra-from-common-light-sources/

  [3]: https://www.hamamatsu.com/jp/en/product/alpha/R/4153/S10917-35GT/index.html

Comment: I don't believe the first solution will work. I would go towards the analysis of the *frequency* and/or the waveform shape (I am assuming we are speaking of AC powered sources?). Obviously daylight is DC. Fluorescent and incandescent will have different waveforms. But I guess you will need to conduct some experiments with different approaches.

Comment: An alternative to processing the spectrograph with a camera is to place an array of sensors directly in the locations where the spectrograph is projected. These sensors would be non-selective photo-detectors (respond to a wide frequency range). You wouldn't be able to achieve high precision like this, but it might suffice for measuring color temperature and CRI, which should allow you to differentiate different types of light. I have never done anything like this. But it could work. Would require a bright light source.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, exactly what am thinking, i.e analyzing the waveform shape would be the better route. The only problem is that we'll need to analyze the image with a computer program so the device cannot determine the light source on it's own (at least at the size we need it to be)

Comment: not necessarily. You can start with a frequency-domain analysis (Fourier?) and see the unique patterns.

Comment: I just got 10 RGB laser garden lights for Xmas gifts that use 3 slow rotating diffraction gratings to split the 100mw lasers into a thousand 0.1mW beams with rotating dots in the garden or pool or house.  like hundreds of moving fireflies reflecting off every leaf in the yard.. very cool

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 That is very cool. Now I need to find those!

Comment: 10 pcs $1050 usd , $300 Fed Ex 2 big boxes, 1 week or about $180usd on Amazon, includes cheapo radio remote control 5m and DC brick. RG and non moving goes about<$100

Comment: @Spikes How small do you really need the sensor to be? Are you aware of the computer revolution that made it possible to calculate things with a tiny chip? A DSP is very small. :)

Comment: @pipe For this initial project, the size doesn't really matter but we would like it to be as small as possible so it can be integrated into a range of products. Yes, I am currently looking at those chips.

Comment: Have you considered not only the spectrum but time series of the measurements? One would expect daylight to be very slowly varying but a fire would be flickery.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You really are looking for someone who's already solved this, I suppose. But I don't know of any project, myself. So all I can offer are some thoughts to consider.

On spectrometers:

1. For a spectrometer device, a DVD-RW (don't use DVD-R, as it will absorb substantial bands in the red region) provides 1350 \$\frac{\textrm{lines}}{\textrm{mm}}\$, so that is very cheap and readily available.
2. Small megapixel digital cameras are also cheap. An array could also be used, but these days it seems an entire 2D camera is cheaper and more available. So I wouldn't bother with an array.
3. Using a DVD-RW you can actually separate the yellow spectral lines of
   mercury at 577 nm and 579 nm. (Not with a CD, though.) I've done this, myself, using a DVD-RW and a mercury-argon lamp.
4. Wavelength calibration is cheap. Just get a mercury-argon lamp. You'll get the argon lines in the first minute or so, then the mercury lines will dominate later. From the combination of them, you can easily calibrate your camera pixels vs wavelength. Hg-Ar lamps used for calibration used to cost me about $8, but I expect they are more expensive now.
5. Intensity calibration is expensive. You need a standard lamp, traceable to NIST standards, and these have to be recalibrated after 100 hrs use, or so. They are cheap bulbs, uncalibrated. But the calibration process costs real money. Then you have to set up a proper optical arrangement, too. But this is the only way to figure out just how each of your pixels respond to each of the wavelengths they are being hit with. Frankly, I'd try and avoid any of this and hope I didn't need it or could just apply a basic templated approximation of a standard lamp and not waste money on actual calibration, hoping that what I got was good enough. Or just not bother at all and use a rigged up equation and figure, "oh, well," and see how it goes. Chances are, you can make this step go away and still get useful results if you just think carefully.
6. You probably can consider going from 450 nm to 750 nm, but you cannot hope to exceed an octave with a single grating. You may want some kind of filter involved so that you don't get mixed up spectral energies on the same pixels. Or just don't worry about it and do some experimenting.
7. Optical baffling will be desired to avoid getting extraneous light where it isn't wanted.
8. Tony just reminded me... you'll need a narrow slit -- about as narrow as you can make it. I prefer the use of two old-style razor blades that can be adjusted. One fixed, one movable. But for the card stock paper box, I just used an exacto blade 'very carefully' to create a narrow and uniformly narrow slit.

I've done all this using a sheet of paper (card stock) that I print out and then cut, fold tabs, use Elmer's glue, and create a box with baffles made essentially out of paper. The baffling uses special dark flocking to help absorb and block wayward light. The DVD slides in at the correct angle and a small camera is then placed at the exit. I've used this with my own eye to observe different lighting in the house and it works PERFECTLY well, in my opinion. I have no trouble differentiating between incandescent, fluorescent, and LED lighting sources. And the sun, for that matter. I tried a DVD-R and immediately saw a huge missing band in the red, which is why I'm telling you that you need DVD-RW if you care about that region.

I could publish some plans for all this, I suppose. Location of slit, angle of DVD, etc. While my box design uses the entire DVD-RW (because I wanted to be able to drop in other DVD media and/or a CD (at a different angle so I'd made two different insertion slots for that purpose), only a tiny part of the DVD-RW surface is actually involved (if baffled correctly.) So I also liked using the entire DVD-RW for that reason, as well, because *cutting* the DVD into pieces would stress it and I didn't want to do that, either.

Just by way of a little info, the box used a 70 mm vs 40 mm tilt for the DVD (1350 \$\frac{\textrm{lines}}{\textrm{mm}}\$) and 50 mm vs 40 mm for a CD (625 \$\frac{\textrm{lines}}{\textrm{mm}}\$.) The slit was positioned on the 40 mm face, positioned about 10 mm from one edge in either CD or DVD case.

---

On RGB:

The RGB sensor you mentioned has, as I expected to see, very wide acceptance of wavelengths in each of the three sensors. LEDs tend to have very wide response ranges (they emit and receive over a wide range of wavelengths.) That sensor has modestly overlapping responses. How well all that will work for you, would be a matter of experimentation, I think. You could apply some computer code, instead, using your curves and the response functions of the sensor to see if it would be serviceable. But I'm not going to even try and write it for you. Perhaps the best thing would be for you to knuckle down and buy the sensor and do some testing with it. It may be just fine for your needs. But I can't tell you yes or no, from a quick scan of it. I also haven't tried to do this with RGB, so that's another reason I can't promise anything here and you'll have to just try it for yourself.

---

I liked Eugene's comment about *frequency*, too. Incandescent bulbs (and I've tested this using a very sensitive instrument -- with tens of microKelvin resolution and hundreds of microKelvin accuracy traceable to NIST standards, as I work on such things) will vary about 3% of their amplitude during the AC cycling at 60 Hz. (Would be different with 50 Hz.) Fluorescents operate at mains frequencies and also at high frequencies (both are manufactured and used.) But their emissions are through phosphors, which often have fast response times. (Some phosphors are slow, order of millisecond taus due to depending upon forbidden triplet to singlet transitions. But many of them are quite fast -- microsecond taus.) You may have to do some experimenting here. But I think this could be fruitful, because you can design electronic circuits for very narrow bands if you want to. You'd have to worry about conditioning the signal so that you don't saturate the amplifier chain. But that's doable. I haven't looked at the frequencies used in modern LED bulbs, though. And I'll leave it to you to google up details there. All that said, I think Eugene's point has merit worth examining, as well.

---

Personally? I'd go with the DVD-RW because I have a lot of experience with doing that, know that I can do it easily, quickly, and cheaply, and because I think I could avoid the intensity calibration step to get where you need to go. The cameras are dirt cheap and so is the Hg-Ar lamp for wavelength calibration, periodically. It's almost no work at all. Plus, I already have walked around the house checking out different light sources with a hand-held card-stock box with no electronics at all and was perfectly able to see the differences in various light sources, by eye. So I know I can get there from here.

EDIT: A couple of images from an old fluorescent bulb. One of them across the spectrum and the other zoomed up a bit. Pretty cool separation of the mercury doublet there!
[image: whole spectrum]  [image: zoomed up]

I specialized in binning LEDs for Siemen's OSRAM division years ago, as a contractor. So this stuff comes partly from that experience. We first used expensive spectrophotometers, but switched to Ocean Optics some time later (much cheaper.) But in the meantime I had a lot of fun with DVDs and CDs, used with all that fancy calibration equipment laying about. (Including disappearing filament calibrators, which I forgot to mention above.) Spent a LOT of my time studying human response reports prior to and since the CIE 1931 standard and the later ones in the 1960s. Also really enjoyed Edwin Land's work in the late 1970's and early 1980's -- very interesting stuff.

Comment: +1 for a fascinating and relevant read.  Lots of good leads to follow from here.  Nice one.

Comment: I like this idea.  It has the advantage of being easily tested, and it can switched to use a real diffraction grating if it turns out to work well.

Comment: I don't think absolute intensity is a problem, but it would need to consistently show the same intensity relationships across the spectrum.  That is, you don't care how bright the red or the green is as long as you can rely on rely on the detector always representing them in the same relationship.

Comment: I only choose TRI-phosphor tubes , better than most LEDs 85CRI, 50kh , 88 LPW. F32T8/TL850/ALTO TG Philips

Comment: all the LEDs I buy have better than 1 MacAdams ellipse or tight X,Y tolerances for <500'K bin range

Comment: @JRE I pretty much agree there.

Comment: I've not tried the CD method of diffraction, but looking thru the bottom of a CD-R, I can see the spectrum from deep Red on one side to deep Blue  on the other side, with a "hole" in the middle where green shud be when seeing both R-B spectrum. Tilt angle shifts the spectrum, so you are saying you calibrated the spectral balance with Hg-Ar

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Both CD, DVD suffer from some 1st order diffraction overlapping 2nd order diffraction for some part of visible spectrum - this is pretty awkward to sort out with wavelength-insensitive photodetectors.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Only with DVD-RW. The CD can't be used over the entire range. You can see what can be achieved with the DVD-RW, looking at the pictures I included. I could add some more, I suppose -- nitrogen, hydrogen, neon, and others -- all taken with a simple cardboard box DVD-RW spectrophotometer.

Comment: does it need a pinhole to reduce diffusion? I find my disks are not very flat

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Oh, .. Yeah. I failed to mention the use of a narrow slit. I'll update my post. You are only using a tiny part of the disk, by the way.

Comment: @jonk Thanks very much for the detailed explanation.
As you assumed, I was looking for someone who has worked on this kind of project as I have very limited knowledge on optics, but believe me, your answer above has given me a direction.
As you advised, I will experiment on both solutions (RGB ratio and building a spectrometer) and would also calibrate for experimental purposes. If I am able to pull the calibrations off and get better results, I will of course do so.
For the RGB solution, I think looking for a sensor with a more granular wavelength for each will be better

Comment: @jonk I do not understand point 6. Do you mean I should expand the width of the grating to be able to fit in that size of the spectrum? Can you please expand on the filtering part.

Comment: @Spikes Just read up on gratings, I think. But a single grating can not disperse more than one octave in wavelength without mixing up the spatial positions from higher orders.

Comment: I made an LED intensity tester for my client using CIE corrected Panasonic Si "Light detectors"  PD's with 5V LDO and 10 PD's on 5 degree angular increments all with R matched equal intensity using LEDs binned by NIST traceable equipment, so that luminaire designs can be spacially intensity tested with built in DMM rotary switch and 9V bat. Critical stepped black coned light apertures were essential to reduce cone angle and block stray light , just like used in high end cameras. All PD's were aimed at a 1m distance to target light source with the black box full of PD's tilted towards target

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I did all that using software I developed. We needed to be able to set the white points at different places (D60, for example) and fixed "CIE corrected" light detectors don't do that for you. So I had sub-nanometer datasets on human perception and did all my own calcs. There were multiple projects, though. Too many to list here. Some for binning, some for white balance calibration, etc. I wish we could share experiences here, though. Would be fun.

Comment: i agree :) Since I only bought narrow XY binned colours, And 10% tolerance Iv , it was customer lens for wireless  road studs that needed to be qualified by Philips so angular Iv of their luminaire was what they needed . Skype is an option for this forum. I also had all the spreadsheets from Wendy Davis when she was at NIST

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Human color perception eventually became a kind of specialty for me. Not intentional, but as a result of the work more or less, plus doing a sweeping review of the literature going back to when Sears would pay universities to help it create consistently colored paints back in the very early 1900's (or so), well before the first CIE 1931 result. I'm sure I'd still learn more from your experiences, though. One person can only experience just so much.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Never used Skype before. Wouldn't know how to. Old fogey, in that way, I suppose. Now, I kind of wish I knew how. But I don't.

Comment: I rarely use it but all you need is a computer or iPad and a video cam with mic then register by  email address and add by user handle or email addr

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I'll have to figure it out at some point. Means software and learning more stuff. I don't even own a video cam, by the way. Have a smart phone, but never even used its video ability, and rarely its camera. But this is probably one of those barriers I need to climb over.

Comment: Since I retired at 54 , in last 10yrs,  meddled with buying millions of custom made LEDs to my specs to match clients expectations for basically a 16 Candella D45 LED with ESD protection.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Interesting. I worked on using LEDs as standard candles. Obviously, they have to be heated up and held at a constant temp. The 48 hour bake-in period found and eliminated about 99.4% of them. Only a few settle down enough to really be good. Most just flitter around. And this is with 0.1% precision current sources. Most LEDs aren't much good for this. Yet people seem to imagine that if the current is controlled well, the LED emits consistently. Nope!

Comment: I also had a calibrated photometer to compare but after a few fringe phosphor molecules burns off and any nanometer impurities in the substrate, the ones I use are pretty stable if Tj is reasonable, but then we can only detect 10% differences if there are 100 others and only 1 one different, and 1% Iv difference with more reference light sources. Just like we can barely tell the difference in 3dB audio unless it is modulated (ref), so LED TV's are what ?? within 10% (I think) not 1%

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 We needed these to be rock solid stable and traceable back to NIST standards. No phosphor, these were just reds. We weren't looking for photopic standards, but radiometric standards. If you were using phosphor based devices, likely that was photopic, yes? Or do I misunderstand?

Comment: Since these lights were used in Autobauns,  Swiss tunnels and Aussie lane dividers they were used under scotopic conditions (night) but the German and other test standards were in Candella at a known distance but wavelengths in phototic LambdaD ( dominant) nm is standard

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the geometry of the self-built diffractor with DVD and paper baffle. An image maybe? Thanks

Comment: @OlafM I'll have to draw up something, then. I'll try and do that at some point today or tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to agree with jonk, but suggest a simpler method of identifying sources.

Build a spectrometer with camera (using a DVD or other diffraction grating.) Make it mechanically solid so that the camera, the grating, and the screen can't move in relation to one another.

Don't bother with calibration - at all.  You will also want to disable automatic white balance in the camera and use a fixed white balance.

Expose your detector to examples of the different light sources you want to detect, and record the images.

Now, you can use your pick of signal processing methods to detect which of your stored spectrograms most matches the current spectrogram.

OpenCV or Gnu Octave or SciPy all present workable methods to detect similarities.

Comment: Yeah, should work. But wavelength calibration is so dirt easy, I'd do it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of great answers here already, but to provide some specific comments to your final questions:

> Is there any drawback on my first solution?

The drawback is that you only have three datapoints (r,g,b) to judge the color, and, depending on the different light sources you are trying to distinguish, you might not be able to tell them apart. This is the same problem that a digital camera encounters when it tries to set the white balance, and sometimes, the camera guesses wrong and the colors of the photo are distorted. However, if you allowed a digital camera to image a known object, like the same white piece of paper, then it would likely be able to distinguish the source of the light most of the time.

> is there a sensor out there that can analyse a light emission and provide intensity values on a range of chosen wavelengths?

A grating (or prism) based spectrometer does exactly that; it provides the light intensity as a function of wavelength.

Alternatively, if you want just a few sensors, you could simple take a silicon photodetector and place the appropriate optical filter (colored glass) in front of it to only allow the wavelength range of interest to pass to the filter. An advantage of this approach would be that the single photodetectors could likely operate more quickly than an array detector, and may allow you to look at the temporal structure of the light and spot characteristic patterns, such as the 60 Hz fluctuation of a lightbulb or the rapid flickering of a flame.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to build your own spectrometer, devices are already available off the shelf, like this ultra compact [C12666MA from Hamamatsu](https://www.hamamatsu.com/resources/pdf/ssd/c12666ma_kacc1216e.pdf).

The 15 nm spectral resolution could be just fine for this task.

It is also a good idea to tell DC and 50/60 Hz apart, maybe with a separate sensor.

Answer (score 1):

Cameras work so some extent exactly the way you show the RGB sensors. If you had had experience trying to capture saturated colours of LEDs in high density light, you will understand it's limitations, but for broad spectrum photo's as we know it works fine.

It depends what you want to measure.

For example white light is just our perception of RGB sensors in our eyes and incident light can fool us into think daylight white is just the balance of Blue and yellow-red phosphor converted light so that the peaks are equal (when converted to CIE eye correction levels)

But the reality is quite different when we compare a Halogen source on a broad pallet of reflected colours and compare with a daylight 4500-5000'K 81% CRI White LED.  Now the colours look different due to the missing spectrum in the source.

For accuracy, your only hope is a calibrated diffraction method instrument.  For rough eyeball incident colours reflected off gradient scale  paper with a full colour gamut, an RGB camera will work. close enough with a calibrated RGB sensor/detector unit and software. But this is not how they do it in industry, but that's basically how paper scanners work with internal RGB + B/W calibration before the scan begins.

Professional light spectrum analyzers measure x,y , u,v and many other parameters of white light.

Comment: I have always used the Microsoft boot "retro"  waving RGBY flag to eyeball the display colour balance and measure the symmetry of the corners to see if the display was out of calibration, but now use DPT.exe to calibrate the whole gamma range for ideal balance and BW saturation levels using video toolbar for card to calibrate TV and 1080p monitor colours

Answer (score 1):

Thus is an old question, and I wonder what was the solution, but looking through the answers I am quite surprised not to see a rather obvious solution.

First, you don’t need to analyze the whole spectrum. Just sample it in a way that maximizes the separation of the sources. Given that you have relatively few sources you can do this by eye, or actually run a PCA or ICA analysis on a discrete version of the expected spectrum. Once you have selected a handful of spectral regions you can proceed.

Second, I would seriously consider the infrared region. Primarily because a fire would have abundant emission there, but most importantly because sensors in this region are very common.

Third, select a discrete sensor or sensor/filter combination that provides you with good enough spectral response in your first desired band. Note that there are many inexpensive filters, photodiodes, phototransistors, and PIR devices that can be selected by wavelength (even single-color LEDs can work in a pinch).

Fourth, if you are doing this mathematically, project your expected responses into the response of the sensor/filter and subtract it away so that you can repeat the procedure with the next significant band. If not, just overlap and estimate what region is next.

Note that filters can also be used to remove bands. If two sensors cover the perfect area, but their responses have too much overlap, subtracting the overlapping band would increase their discrimination. .

After repeating this two or three times, you will have a small set of inexpensive sensors that you can use. Put some circuitry around them, and calibrate your response with a few known sources. If you did the separation correctly, you will only need a rough calibration for the sensitivity of your filter/sensor/circuitry design.

This is basically the RGB sensor idea, but using properly tuned wavelength bins instead of rather arbitrary ones.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need very high radiometric sensitivity, collimate it, run it through a grating, and dump the image on a linear sensor array. Analyzing the spectrum is easy if you have a microprocessor. The temporal variation alone isn't likely to work very well since consumer lighting systems vary widely in flicker frequencies. The only things that will be hard to distinguish from the spectrum are the incandescent and flames. You might use the temporal variation for that, working under the assumption that the flame will be pretty random and the incandescent should have a distinct 60 Hz component. Beware though that electronics have a tendency to pick up stray 60 Hz, so you'll have to make sure you're seeing 60 Hz light and not 60 Hz noise. The linear sensors are a cheap and simple part that you shouldn't have any trouble interfacing.
The only way I could see this working with 3 channels is if you were only trying to classify the flame and you could dump all the other light sources into a "don't care" pile. In that case, you can pretty reasonably take anything with, say, way more NIR than blue emission to be either incandescent or flame. If you're willing to work with MWIR detectors, you can skip the temporal variation and just look for the CO2 emission peak though. The incandescent shouldn't have that. That's what a lot of commercial sensors use.